# Codeigniter - Passing the value of column to the column of another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I getting **Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'** error

i like to do is what ever random numeric inserted to invoice column i should pass it to the column transaction_num of another table.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
$order = array(
           'date' => $date,
           'customer_id' => $cust_id,
           'invoice' => random_string('numeric', 6)
           );
    $ord_id = $this->PaymentModel->insert_order($order);

    $invoice = $this->PaymentModel->get_invoice($ord_id);

$order_detail = array(
        'transaction_num' => $invoice,

//there is other data to be inserted here i just removed it coz this column is the only problem
                );
$this->PaymentModel->insert_order_detail($order_detail);
```

**MY PAYMENT MODEL**

```
public function get_invoice($ord_id){

        $query = $this->db->select('invoice')->from('orders')->where('serial', $ord_id)->get(); 
        return $query->result_array();


}
public function insert_order_detail($order_detail) {
    $this->db->insert('order_detail', $order_detail);

}
```

Comment: what is the error line ?

Comment: @FastSnail ive tried to change my code now based on what is given code below now ive getting this errror http://prnt.sc/bzcpzd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
public function get_invoice($ord_id){

        $query = $this->db->select('invoice')->from('orders')->where('serial', $ord_id)->get(); 
        return $query->result_array();


}
```

to

```
   public function get_invoice($ord_id){

            $this->db->where('serial', $ord_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('invoice')->row_array(); 
            return $query['invoice'];


    }
```

/////////////////////////////or//////////////////////

I am assuming you are doing above functionality in same function.So, you can just store

$invoice=random_string('numeric', 6);

and supply this to both tables

Comment: that is other issue please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/3239572

Comment: remove  space before <?php and after ?>

Comment: what you mean remove space before <?php and after ?> '<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');' here's my from the top

Comment: if there is whitespace before <?php this may cause headers issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118686/discussion-between-moknathal-and-edgar-ong).

Comment: ive already firxed the problem. based on the link you give to men a while ago. i have plenty of echo that's why. btw thanks again for the help